# Multiple File Upload using Carrierwave and JQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, formtastic

```
<%= semantic_form_for(@image, :url => { :action => "create_friend_upload" }, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
     <%= f.input :image, :input_html => {:multiple => true}, name: "gallery[image]" %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :friend_upload, :value => true %>    
     <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
     <%= f.hidden_field :friend_uploader, :value => current_user.name %>
    <% end %>
     <%= f.buttons do %>
     <%= f.commit_button :button_html => {:class => "primary"} %>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

The problem I is that it keeps on submitting an array, which Carrierwave can't handle. It keeps saying `name=\"gallery[image][]\"` instead of just `name=\"gallery[image]\"`.  (See below).  Because of it, I also keep getting the error message `can't convert nil into String`.

```
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gallery[image][]\"; filename=\"VW 3.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
```

Anyone know how to solve this?  Thanks!

**update:**

I did see Ryan's railscasts video on JQuery as well, his fix for this didn't work for me.

Gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :image, :name, :friend_upload, 
  mount_uploader :image, GalleryUploader
end
```

Gallery controller

```
def friend_upload
 @image = Gallery.new
end

def create_friend_upload
 @image = Gallery.create(params[:gallery])
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the Gallery model declarations?

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW, I updated the question with model and controller for gallery.  Thanks.

Comment: You could try bypassing carrierwave, and uploading directly your files to s3, as described here : http://pjambet.github.com/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/ , the example is for one file, but with a file input multiple, it works great.

Comment: hi @pjam, by doing this, would I lose the resizing functionalities?  I need these functionalities, otherwise it will be hard to maintain consistent sizing and clean UI.

Comment: Hum indeed, this would cause some problems as you'll probably won't be able to use the processing via carrier wave, however I know it's not that hard to use RMagick for that purpose, you just need to write more code :s

Answer (score 4):

Because you were specifying `:multiple => true`, rails generates `name="gallery[image][]"`. You may also experience this issue when upgrading to the lastest version of rails (3.2.13) due to https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8108.

The simple fix would be something along the lines of

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    paramName: 'gallery[image]'
});
```

This utilizes the `paramName` option to specify the file form data

References:

- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#paramname
- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1529

Comment: I was running into this issue due to the change in 3.2.13, and it was driving me nuts…so confused until I found your answer. Thank you!!

Comment: I first though it was a specific problem to Rails 4, thank you for this elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because you didnt put `name` inside of `input_html`, thats the thing with using `simple form` and probably `semantic form` as well